# Can someone explain why this simplification works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOLuF.png

I don't understand wouldn't -x+x cancel out to become 0?

Comment: $-x+\frac x 2$ is not the same as $\frac {-x+x} 2$.

Comment: By that thought, are you suggesting that $1-\frac1{1000}=0$?

Comment: What $x$?  You don't have an $x$.  You have $\frac x 2$ or one-half of an $x$.

Comment: Consider $1 - \frac 12$.  The $1 -1$ don't cancel and become $0$ because you don't *have* $1-1$.  The $1$ is the numerator of a fraction and not a whole number at all.  This is the exact same thing $-x +\frac x2$ then you don't have $-x +x$.  Then $x$ is the numerator of a fraction and not a whole value of $x$ and all.  It is *half* of a value of $x$.  It's is exaclty the same $1- \frac 12 \ne \frac {1-1}2$ and $-x +\frac x2 \ne\frac {-x + x}2$.  Indeed the $\frac x2$ is one *half* of $x$. and $-x +\frac x = -x + \frac 12x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check that $$x-\dfrac{x}{2}=\dfrac{\color{red}{2}x}{\color{red}{2}}-\dfrac{x}{2}=\dfrac{x}{2}.$$